# cannot generate ctags for php traits

Tags: ctags, filetype-php

I'm using vim, and I have used ctags and placed this in the ctags config file as per [this](https://ericjmritz.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/finding-php-traits-with-exuberant-ctags/) post:

```
--regex-php=/^[ \t]*trait[ \t]+([a-z0_9_]+)/\1/t,traits/i
```

the problem is that I still can't find the trait.. so for example in this code:

```
    /*Mark user as verified first*/
    $user = App\User::find($this->getClient()->id);
    $user->is_verified = true;
```

pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on my mac returns this:

```
> tags
 prt  path  <mru>={ files }=<buf> <->                                                                                                                                                                                                          /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api
>>> _
```

jumping to definition in php storm on the same file works fine, and takes me here:

trait ClientHelpers{

```
private $client      = null;
private $clientToken = null;


/*JWT*/
protected function getClient()
{
    if (!$this->client) {
        $this->setClientToken();
    }
    return $this->client;
}
```

ideas?

## update

i checked the contents of my tags file, and `getClient` exists there!

```
getClient       tests/Helpers/ClientHelpers.php /^    protected function getClient()$/;"        f       trait:ClientHelpers
```

which is weird. for completion sake, here is my [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/abbood/d66bdf176abdd5a50625c188d876b6e3) file.

## second update

`:tags getClient` works!

and i removed this part from my [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/abbood/d66bdf176abdd5a50625c188d876b6e3) file
    " The Silver Searcher
    if executable('ag')
      " Use ag over grep
      set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor\ --ignore\ tags

```
  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g --ignore tags""'

  " ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif
```

and now when i enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on top of getClient I get this

[image]

[image]

## update 3

it turns out i was pressing the wrong key.. :( it works fine now!

Comment: Perhaps you should try-out another implementation of ctags. Exuberant ctag development is stalled for years but there is an active fork: [Universal ctags](https://ctags.io/). Perhaps it already support the feature you want.

Comment: that's the one i got installed.. ```$ ctags --version
Universal Ctags 0.0.0(ccac4df), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Oct 19 2017, 12:02:27
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +multibyte, +option-directory, +xpath, +case-insensitive-filenames```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> in normal mode, you are invoking the [Ctrl-P plugin](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim), and it is displaying a fuzzy finder for files, (with the first entry being the `tags` file you've created with ctags).

If your cursor is over `getClient()`, the keystroke you need to use to jump to its definition is <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd>.

If this doesn't work, then the first thing to check is whether the `getClient` tag actually exists in your tags file. You can do this by opening it in Vim and searching. If the tag doesn't exist, then you'll need to fix the command you are using to invoke ctags.

Comment: my bad i mistyped the key combo i was using, it was indeed ctrl-] all along. _then you'll need to fix the command you are using to invoke ctags._.. that's exactly what i'm asking

Comment: @abbood You also copied and pasted the Ctrl-P output into your question, so it looks like you've remapped `ctrl-]` to invoke Ctrl-P too.

Comment: normally when i press ctrl-] i go to the definition. it's just that when i do that with traits, it doesn't find it.. [this](https://gist.github.com/abbood/d66bdf176abdd5a50625c188d876b6e3) is the contents of my vimrc file though

Comment: but you are right about getclient being inside my tags file.. so now i'm not sure what's going on 

Comment: @abbood Does `:tag getClient` work correctly?

Comment: yes it does! i just tested it

Comment: i updated my question with some more stuff

Comment: @abbood Glad it's working now!